# Is there a way to use pattern matching to remove redis keys in bulk?

Tags: redis

I have hundreds of thousands of keys that start with `html:` that I need to clean up quickly. Instead of writing a python script to do this, I was hoping for a simple command via redis-cli to do this. I was surprised to not find one. I am assuming I can do something with `xargs` from the linux terminal but I need to also pass in the auth password to redis.

Answer (score 0):

After some munging and experimentation, I found this combination to work perfectly to remove all the keys I needed that match the beginning from left to right in the key name itself. It was very fast to run, which is no surprise since redis is in memory.

```
redis-cli -a <mypassword> --raw keys "html:*" | xargs redis-cli -a <mypassword> del
```